# Installing Kernel 3.5.1 breaks boot up

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I have twice tried to update my kernel from 3.2.0.30 to 3.5.1 on my Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit system using two different methods I found via google.  In both cases the operation appeared to run flawlessly and when I rebooted grub found the new Kernel and began to boot it.  During boot-up I was some normal looking progress then an error about /dev/hda and bad args followed by the display getter dimmer until it was barely visile.  I never got to the Ubuntu splash screens nor any additional text onscreen.

So, how do I upgrade to a later, specific, kernel, 3.5.1 without breaking my boot?  I am running on an Intel Q7 board made by Congatec with a usb attached drive.